# SharePoint online site collection - Add a Google link to Structural Navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have an online site collection.  I want to add a Google link to each sub-site at the current structural navigation and I don't want to do it manually.  Each sub-site is set not to inherit the parent navigation.  Does anyone have a good script that can do this?  I'm not very good at putting pieces together, so the more complete the script is, the better.

Thanks 
Sandy

Answer (score 0):

Use [Add-PnPNavigationNode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpnavigationnode?view=sharepoint-ps) PnP cmdlet to add an item to a navigation element.

```
#connect to your tenant
Connect-PnPOnline –Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com –Credentials (Get-Credential)
$nurl = "<url>"
Add-PnPNavigationNode -Title "<title>" -Location "QuickLaunch" -Url $nurl
```

Iterate through subsites in the site collection and add navigation items.

[PnP PowerShell overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps&f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)